# How do I make a Website Appear after my loading animation?

Tags: html, css, animation

So what I did was to make a CSS animation of a loading text, and I wanted a webpage to come?

I didn't include the web info, since I need To add it:
HTML:

```
`<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Glowing Loading Text Animation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>
<span>L</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>a</span>
<span>d</span>
<span>i</span>
<span>n</span>
<span>g</span>
<span>...</span>
</h2>
</body>
</html>`
```

CSS:

```
*
{
    margin:0;
    padding:0;
    font-family:consolas;
    
}
body
{
    display: flex;
    justify-content: center;
    align-items: center;
    min-height: 100vh;
    background: #000;
}
h2
{
    color: #000;
    font-size: 6em;
    display: flex;
}
h2 span
{
    animation: animate 4s linear infinite;  
}
h2 span:nth-child(1)
{
    animation-delay: 0s;
}
h2 span:nth-child(2)
{
    animation-delay: 0.1s;
}
h2 span:nth-child(3)
{
    animation-delay: 0.2s;
}
h2 span:nth-child(4)
{
    animation-delay: 0.3s;
}
h2 span:nth-child(5)
{
    animation-delay: 0.4s;
}
h2 span:nth-child(6)
{
    animation-delay: 0.5s;
}
h2 span:nth-child(7)
{
    animation-delay: 0.6s;
}
h2 span:nth-child(8)
{
    animation-delay: 0.7s;
}
@keyframes animate 
{
    0%,100%
    {
        color:#fff;
        filter: blur(2px);
        text-shadow: 0 0 10px #00b3ff,
                     0 0 20px #00b3ff,
                     0 0 40px #00b3ff,
                     0 0 80px #00b3ff,
                     0 0 120px #00b3ff,
                     0 0 200px #00b3ff,
                     0 0 300px #00b3ff,
                     0 0 400px #00b3ff;
    }
}
    25%,75%
    {
        color:#000;
        filter: blur(0px);
        text-shadow:none;
    }
}
body:after {
  content: "";
  display: none;
}

@keyframes animate {
  0%, 100% {
    color: #fff;
    filter: blur(2px);
    text-shadow: 0 0 10px #00b3ff,
      0 0 20px #00b3ff,
      0 0 40px #00b3ff,
      0 0 80px #00b3ff,
      0 0 120px #00b3ff,
      0 0 200px #00b3ff,
      0 0 300px #00b3ff,
      0 0 400px #00b3ff;
  }

  25%, 75% {
    color: #000;
    filter: blur(0px);
    text-shadow: none;
  }
}

@keyframes showWebsite {
  100% {
    display: block;
  }
}

#website {
  display: none;
  animation: showWebsite 4s linear forwards;
}
```

Any suggestions, Fixes or Javascript to be added?(Specific please)
I know many similar phrased questions were asked, but I haven't found anything.Please Help?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

I think what you want to achieve if, after some time the page automatically send you to another html page correct ? You can achieve this using Javascript.

```js
setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "new-page.html";
}, 3000);
```

What you need to do is add a `<script></script>` tag to you first html page where you have the loading effect and put the function inside, like this:

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Glowing Loading Text Animation</title>
<link rel="stylesheet" href="main.css">
</head>
<body>
<center>
<h2>
<span>L</span>
<span>o</span>
<span>a</span>
<span>d</span>
<span>i</span>
<span>n</span>
<span>g</span>
<span>...</span>
</h2>
<script>
  setTimeout(function() {
    window.location.href = "new-page.html";
  }, 3000);
</script>
</body>
</html>
```

Where `new-page.html` is the name if the other html page you have.

You can control the time of the redirect modified the `3000` parameter that the functions have.

Comment: Thanks very much @Materanol! This definitely is a good solution, but I want the code of my website in the same html file. How to achieve this?

Answer (score 1):

On this occasion, you can make a main div that contains your main website and a loader div that contains your loader. and add javascript for when your webpage is fully loaded.

below could be a sample:

```js
document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    loader = document.getElementById('loader');
});
```

also here is your sample with js

```js
var loader;
function loadNow(opacity) {
    if (opacity <= 0) {
        displayContent();
    } else {
        loader.style.opacity = opacity;
        window.setTimeout(function() {
            loadNow(opacity - 0.05);
        }, 10);
    }
}

function displayContent() {
    loader.style.display = 'none';
}

document.addEventListener("DOMContentLoaded", function() {
    loader = document.getElementById('loader');
    loadNow(1);
});
```

```css
#loader {
  position: fixed;
  width: 100%;
  height: 100vh;
  z-index: 1;
  overflow: visible;
  background: #fff;
}

#spinner {
  text-align: center;
  animation-name: spin, depth;
  animation-timing-function: linear;
  animation-iteration-count: infinite;
  animation-duration: 3s;
}
```

```html
<!DOCTYPE html>
<html lang="en">
<head>
<meta charset="utf-8">
<title>Glowing Loading Text Animation</title>
</head>

<body>
  <div id="loader">
    <div id="spinner">
      <span>L</span>
      <span>o</span>
      <span>a</span>
      <span>d</span>
      <span>i</span>
      <span>n</span>
      <span>g</span>
      <span>...</span>
    </div>
  </div>
      

<div class="main">

<img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/486/536/354.jpg?hmac=BOxuZ3jR_LErHK6qloUMI7FZuu6FPb5up2VYAbZKNOc"/>
<img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/486/536/354.jpg?hmac=BOxuZ3jR_LErHK6qloUMI7FZuu6FPb5up2VYAbZKNOc"/>
<img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/486/536/354.jpg?hmac=BOxuZ3jR_LErHK6qloUMI7FZuu6FPb5up2VYAbZKNOc"/>
<img src="https://fastly.picsum.photos/id/486/536/354.jpg?hmac=BOxuZ3jR_LErHK6qloUMI7FZuu6FPb5up2VYAbZKNOc"/>
</div>
  

</body>

</html>
```

**NB:** you can see when the image loading completed the loader will fade away.

Comment: this is definitely very helpful! But, what I am trying to achieve is, the loading text should come first, and it should go and the HTML body should prop up, Will it do that?

Comment: you can add some `css` to it. (I updated the answer)

Comment: Unfortunately, It didn't work.